# Plymouth theme works during shut down, but not during boot

Tags: themes, plymouth

I have installed Aurora-Penguinis-2 following [these](https://bitbucket.org/gemlion/aurora-penguinis/src/4c84581055716d888674b2479d6ee1452a99fb47/Aurora-Penguinis-Plymouth-2/Readme.md?fileviewer=file-view-default) instructions. I changed `/lib/plymouth` to `/usr/share/plymouth`

The theme loads at shutdown, but only blank screen appears at startup, then lightDM starts.

I am using Xenial.

The contents of the .plymouth file is

> [Plymouth Theme]
>
> Name=Aurora-Penguinis-Plymouth-2
>
> Description=A theme that features a background with a logo.
>
> ModuleName=script
>
> [script]
>
> ImageDir=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/Aurora-Penguinis-Plymouth-2
>   ScriptFile=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/Aurora-Penguinis-Plymouth-2/aurora-penguinis-2.script

Comment: did you remember `sudo update-initramfs -u`?

Comment: Yes I did. And the result is `update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-26-generic` `W: plymouth module (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/plymouth//.so) missing, skipping that theme.` `Warning: No support for locale: en_IN`

Comment: the warning is why it doesn't show. you have multiarch. is your machine 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: 64 bit machine, 64 bit os

Comment: there is an error in the script for the theme. check this line `ModuleName=` be sure ther isn't a space between = and the name

Comment: There is no space

Comment: `/.so`  this is the problem .. If it has a script then the line should be `ModuleName=script`. can you post the contents of the ".plymouth" file for the theme?

Comment: @ravery I have included it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71722/discussion-between-ravery-and-archisman-panigrahi).

Comment: @ravery did this ever get resolved?

Comment: @AChildofGod I don't remember. I don't have that installation anymore :-)